# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '' in [object]

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vue-component

I am using vue.js and laravel 5.8.
In my commenting system like youtube,

> I want to show user's profile image.
>
> If user doesn't have a profile image, I want to show avatar.

I have many users, so I want to show multiple profile images based on id.

Now I got this error.

> "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '' in
>   1571585278.jpg"

[image: errors]

According to this console errors, I am fetching profile image (1571585278.jpg).
But I cannot show it, because 'in' operator is not available.

Also, I cannot show user's avatar. Though I used if method.

```
<div else class="user" >
        <avatar :username="comment.user.name" :size="45"></avatar>
 </div>
```

I am storing images in public/uploads.

> How to fix Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to
>   search for '' in ?

**user.php**

```
protected $with = ['profile'];
```

**comment.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="reply-comment" >
        <div class="user-comment">
                <div class="user" v-if="comment.user.profile.image && comment.user.profile.image.length > 0">
                    <span :v-for="(item, index) in comment.user.profile.image">
                        <img :src="'/uploads/' + item.comment.user.profile.image">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div else class="user" >
                    <avatar :username="comment.user.name" :size="45"></avatar>
                </div>
            <div class="user-name">
                <span class="comment-name"><a :href=" '/user/' + 'profile' +'/'+ comment.user.id + '/'  ">{{ comment.user.name }}</a></span>
                <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reply">
        <button @click="addingReply = !addingReply" class="reply-button" :class="{ 'red' : !addingReply, 'black' : addingReply }">
            {{ addingReply ? 'Cancel' : 'Add Reply'}}
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="user-reply-area" v-if="addingReply">
        <div class="reply-comment">
            <div  v-if="!auth">
                <button @click="addReply" class="comment-button">Reply</button>
                <input v-model='body' type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <replies ref='replies' :comment="comment"></replies>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Avatar from 'vue-avatar'
import Replies from './replies.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        Avatar,
        Replies
    },
    data() {
        return {
            body: '',
            addingReply: false,
            auth: '',
            item: '',
            index: ''
        }
    },
    props: {
        comment: {
            required: true,
            default: () => ({})
        },
        post: {
            required: true,
            default: () => ({})
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addReply() {
            if(! this.body) return
            axios.post(`/comments/${this.post.id}`, {
                comment_id: this.comment.id,
                body: this.body
            }).then(({data})=> {
                this.body = ''
                this.addingReply = false
                this.$refs.replies.addReply(data)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        });
     }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: your `comment` is the one responsible for the `object` that you are looking for.

It should be like this. `v-for="item in comment"` then you can loop through the comment like `item.user.profile.image`. One thing that doesn't clear you are not using naming convention if it is an object or array use a `plural form`, then when its a single instance you use `singular form`

Comment: Thanks, but, I have a new error Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined"..

Comment: in your `laravel` backend you should use the `with` property. `$comments = Comments::with('profile')->all();`

Comment: Thanks again, but another problem is, image is undefined...